# When calling the wp_logout function the page stops working

Tags: php, html

I have my page working correctly to put the logout button like this:

```
<a class="rad-notification-content lg-text" href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
```

or

```
<a class="rad-notification-content lg-text" href="sair.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
```

[image]

But if you put the logout button in this way to call the wp_logout function it blocks the page, as I show:

```
<a class="rad-notification-content lg-text" href="<?php wp_logout(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
```

The page looks like this:

[image]

All html disappears and either the button to open the menu or the location of the photo to appear, clicking the option to log out does not work

Comment: What is the purpose of `href="<?php wp_logout(); ?>"`? That function performs the actual logout (which you presumably don’t want to happen at this point already), and why are you sticking it inside the `href` attribute in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe So how can I call this function on my button to log out of the website?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hyperlink which points on a file containing the logout function e.g. `<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>`, but you cannot call a function inside the href attribute.